# angular6 - service @Injectable provideIn

Tags: angular

I'm quite confused on the provideIn addition for the tree-shaking.
I've a folder `test` that contain `test.module.ts` `test.component.ts` `test.service.ts`
The question is I should use:
1) In the service:

`@Injectable({
  providedIn: TestModule,
})`

2)or in the module:

`providers: [TestService]`

and why the first solution or the second?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

for angular6
you should use 1 (providedIn root) for make a injectable singleton service to all the application, or provideIn X for produce the instance of that service only when X is loaded.

2 could be usefull to override the injection with another new implementation (testing?)

Angular 6 introduces provideIn because previusly all services was globaly asigned as providers of the root bundle and being instanced at start despite of them not being used by any module.

Answer (score 0):

Official Angular doc **Where to configure providers**

https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection#where-to-register

> Instead of specifying the root injector, you can set providedIn to a
>   specific NgModule.
>
> ...
>
> This is generally no different from configuring the injector of the
>   NgModule itself, except that the service is tree-shakable if the
>   NgModule doesn't use it. It can be useful for a library that offers a
>   particular service that some components might want to inject
>   optionally, and leave it up to the app whether to provide the service.

Answer (score -1):

The difference is..
1) For each module instance, you'll have a service instance.
2) You'll have the same instance for each component.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. can you give me an example to better understand please? By the way I don't think is a -1 question...it's not clear in the doc